# Create a kind of Interface c++

Tags: c++, frameworks, interface

I'm writing a little 2d rendering framework with managers for input and resources like textures and meshes (for 2d geometry models, like quads) and they are all contained in a class "engine" that interacts with them and with a directX class. So each class have some public methods like init or update. They are called by the engine class to render the resources, create them, but a lot of them should not be called by the user:

```
//in pseudo c++
//the textures manager class
class TManager
{
  private:
     vector textures;
     ....
  public:
     init();
     update();
     renderTexture();
     //called by the "engine class"

     loadtexture();
     gettexture();
     //called by the user
}


class Engine
{
private:
   Tmanager texManager;

public:
     Init() 
     { 
       //initialize all the managers
     }
     Render(){...}
     Update(){...}

     Tmanager* GetTManager(){return &texManager;} //to get a pointer to the manager 
                                                  //if i want to create or get textures
}
```

In this way the user, calling Engine::GetTmanager will have access to all the public methods of Tmanager, including init update and rendertexture, that must be called only by Engine inside its init, render and update functions.
So, is it a good idea to implement a user interface in the following way?

```
//in pseudo c++
//the textures manager class
class TManager
{
  private:
     vector textures;
     ....
  public:
     init();
     update();
     renderTexture();
     //called by the "engine class"

     friend class Tmanager_UserInterface;
     operator Tmanager_UserInterface*(){return reinterpret_cast<Tmanager_UserInterface*>(this)}
}

class Tmanager_UserInterface : private Tmanager
{
  //delete constructor
  //in this class there will be only methods like:

   loadtexture();
   gettexture();
}

class Engine
{
private:
   Tmanager texManager;

public:
     Init() 
     Render()
     Update()

     Tmanager_UserInterface* GetTManager(){return texManager;}
}

//in main function
   //i need to load a texture
   //i always have access to Engine class 

engine->GetTmanger()->LoadTexture(...) //i can just access load and get texture;
```

In this way i can implement several interface for each object, keeping visible only the functions i (and the user) will need.

There are better ways to do the same?? Or is it just useless(i dont hide the "framework private functions" and the user will learn to dont call them)?

Before i have used this method:

```
class manager
{
 public:
   //engine functions

   userfunction();
}

class engine
{ 
 private:
 manager m;
  public:
   init(){//call manager init function}

   manageruserfunciton()
   {
    //call manager::userfunction()
   }
}
```

in this way i have no access to the manager class but it's a bad way because if i add
a new feature to the manager i need to add a new method in the engine class and it takes a lot of time.

sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Anytime I see "interface", and with it an intentional *lack* of `virtual` or references/pointers, I'm stymied. And `reinterpret_cast` should be a giant red flag something may not be "right".

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` is decidedly not a good way to do things. The use of `init` functions instead of using C++ constructors is probably not a good way to do things. It's a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve, what the goal is.

Comment: I dont really have a goal. But since adding a class without members but just with methods souldn't change the size of the class all the interface methods will work. I was simple asking myself if you can do something like that, in c++, if a binary code would ALWAYS works. i tried with two simple classes with no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your method, but it's better to derive private interface from public:

```
class TexManagerPublic
{
public:
    virtual void load() = 0;
    virtual void save() = 0;
};
class TexManagerPrivate : public TexManagerPublic
{
public:
    void load();
    void save();
    void init();
    void update();
};
class Engine
{
    TexManagerPrivate theTexManager;
public:
    Engine() { theTexManager.init(); }
    TexManagerPublic* texManager() { return &theTexManager; }
};
```

Or you can make an 'Engine' to be friend to TextureManager like this:

```
class TexManager
{
private:
    void init();
    void update();
    friend class Engine;
};
class Engine
{
    TexManager texManager;
    void init()
    {
        texManager.init();
    }
};
```

Comment: I have already thought about the "friend method", but mine was just an example, my framework is more complicated and classes are encapsulate in different way, so there are more "engine private functions" and more objects and so each class will have a lot of friend classes and it will be a lot of mess. Derive private from public may be a good idea, but since it will be a game engine i prefer avoid virtual functions (and if i have to choose i will leave public the "like-init" functions). And my first question if you can use my method safely without bugs or errors.

Comment: well i don't really see a reason to avoid virtual functions, but if you want - you can do such things. It looks a bit strange cause of downcast(sign of bad design).

Comment: They are a little slower. Thanks for all.

Comment: I know downcasting is almost a bad thing, but it is not a dynamic cast to a vector element to discovery which derived type is the current object, but a compile time cast(and so a faster way) to "suggest" the correct way to do something, like a IDE tool, but forced by the language, so i dont think it's so bad, yes, a little bit strange...